# Python replace all non-ASCII strings with other strings

Tags: python, ascii

I have been looking around for a while to any kind of solution to my problem the only thing close is how to replace a specific line if i know the non ASCII string already but what i would like to do is a loop for every line in a txt file to find every single non ASCII string and replace it with just the word STRING

variable Name ‘ƒ
variable2 Name2 ƒŠ‡

I have only found people removing all ascii and filling the blanks in between.

Answer (score 3):

Try the Python standard library `re.sub`:

```py
import re
txt = "‘ƒ variable2 Name2 ƒŠ‡"
txt = re.sub(r"[^\x1F-\x7F]+", "STRING", txt)
print(txt)
```

Then use this method for each line in your file.

Comment: That does work thank you , but for some reason , even though it replaces the ones i want , it replaces it twice . so it always is , variable name STRING;STRING

Comment: The regex will replace each block of non-ascii. If you have ascii characters in the middle of a block, it will treat it as two separate blocks

Comment: I dont know i looked evertywhere and i believe the problem to be somewhere in my code but i cant seem to find it . for line in f:
       line = re.sub(r"[^\x1F-\x7F]+", 'STRING', line)
       print(line)
       if 'str' in line:
          break

Comment: Also the txt i use is extremely simple so i dont miss anything but it always gets replaced twice var TextBoxHandle STRING;STRING
var TextBoxHandle STRING;STRING
var TextBoxHandle STRING;STRING
var TextBoxHandle STRING;STRING
var TextBoxHandle STRING;STRING besides the last one

Comment: nevermind im so stupid i just realised what i was doing wrong